# how to send Class<T> to a generic method

Tags: java, class, generics

```
IosPartner extends Partner

AndroidPartner extends Partner
```

I have this code:

```
    Class<T> clazz = partnerStr.contains("itunes")? IosPartner.class : AndroidPartner.class;

    Partner partnerToAdd = jsonUtility.toObject(partnerStr, clazz);
```

and

```
public <T> T toObject(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        if (json == null)
            return null;
...
```

i get a compilation error:

```
Error:(64, 52) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to com.waze.sdkService.operations.uiDto.Partner
```

how should i fix my code to be generalized?

Comment: `Class<T> clazz = partnerStr.contains("itunes")? IosPartner.class : AndroidPartner.class;` shouldn't compile either, but the message would be different, so you have multiple issues. You should update your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), even if it doesn't compile, but just make sure the only compilation error is the one you are asking about. As the question stands, there isn't enough information for me to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is `T` class? Is it another type variable independent of whatever `jsonUtility` expects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that the `Class` object you are passing to `toObject()` is not just any `Class`, but specifically one representing a class that extends `Partner`.  To do that, declare its type like so:

```
Class<? extends Partner> clazz = partnerStr.contains("itunes")
        ? IosPartner.class : AndroidPartner.class;
```

Comment: why `Class clazz = partnerStr.contains("itunes")
        ? IosPartner.class : AndroidPartner.class;` throw compilation error? for `Partner partnerToAdd = jsonUtility.toObject(partnerStr, clazz);`

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a problem of using `T` when you don't have to. Since both classes extend `Partner`, just use `Class<? extends Partner` instead of `Class<T>`

EDIT: @John Bollinger beat me to it.